# Multidimensional Form & Ajax-JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closest

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addrow").click(function () {
       var strToAdd = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="item_code form-control" placeholder="Item Code" name="item_code[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="price form-control" placeholder="price" name="price[]"><td></tr>';
        $('#itemrow').append(strToAdd);    

        $('.item_code').keyup(function () {
            var dataString = $('.item_code').val();
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "itemcode.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { item_code: dataString },
                dataType: "html"
            });
            request.done(function (msg) {
                $(".price").val(msg);
            });
        });
    });
});

<table id="itemrow">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="item_code form-control" placeholder="Item Code" name="item_code[]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="price form-control" placeholder="price" name="price[]">
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="item_code form-control" placeholder="Item Code" name="item_code[]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="price form-control" placeholder="price" name="price[]">
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

HTML Code is added through another javascript using append function. When I enter Item Code for both the fields it only displays data of first one.

[image]

Comment: remove the click event

Comment: Click Event is necessary as table rows are added through jquery.

Comment: use even delegation than

Answer (score 0):

It happends, because you use multiple instances of classes "item_code" and "price". Try this code.

```
$('.item_code').keyup(function() {
var dataString = $(this).val();
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "itemcode.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { item_code : dataString },
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
            $(this).parent().find('.price').val(msg);
}); 
});

});

});
```

Comment: Didn't work. I have edited and placed full code for your reference.

Comment: You should change code here class="invoice_id form-control" to class="item_code form-control"

Comment: That was error in posting the code which I have corrected now. The parent() function is not working. Moreover, whatever I put last-child of item_code it replaces value in all price input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addrow").on('click',function () {
           var strToAdd = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="invoice_id form-control" placeholder="Item Code" name="invoice_id[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="txtHint form-control" placeholder="Item Code" name="txtHint[]"><td></tr>';
            $('#itemrow').append(strToAdd);    
    });
            $('.item_code').on('keyup',function () {
                    var item = $(this);
                var dataString = item.val();
                   })
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "itemcode.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { item_code: dataString },
                    dataType: "html"
                });
                request.done(function (msg) {
                    item.parentsUntil('tr').find('.price').attr('value',msg);
                });
            });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, It got corrected after I added context: this, in the ajax request...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me. Was able to correct the mistake by adding context: this, in the ajax request. Below is full code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#addrow").click(function () {
   var strToAdd = '<tr><td><input type="text" class="item_code form-control" placeholder="Item Code" name="item_code[]"></td><td><input type="text" class="price form-control" placeholder="price" name="price[]"><td></tr>';
    $('#itemrow').append(strToAdd);    

    $('.item_code').keypress(function () {
        var dataString = $(this).closest('tr').find('.item_code').val();

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "itemcode.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { item_code : dataString },
      context: this,
      dataType: "html"
    });
        request.done(function (msg) {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val(msg);
        });
    });
});
});
```